# Rust use BufMut with a buffered reader instance

Tags: rust, tcp, bytestream, buffered

I have a function whose signature is this:

```rs
pub fn handle_decode(buf: &mut bytes::BytesMut) -> anyhow::Result<DataType> {}
```

Which is to be shared between routines which handle different network transfer protocols. The reason I'm using the `bytes` package is because it nicely handles things like endianness and shallow copies. It's very nice for picking off bytes in the right order and "cloning" them cheaply.

With that being said, in the TCP routine I'm looking to use a `BufReader<TcpStream>` to combat the overhead of repeated syscalls to `read()` when picking data off the stream.

Is there any way to use a `bytes::BufMut` in conjunction with a buffered reader to get the best of both worlds?

Minimum example:

```rust
use anyhow::Context;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::net::TcpListener;

fn bind_accept() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    fn handle_decode(buf: &mut bytes::BytesMut) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    let mut l = TcpListener::bind("1234")?;

    let (sock, _) = l.accept().context("should bind to provided port")?;

    let bufreader = BufReader::new(sock);
    let mut buf = bytes::BytesMut::with_capacity(1024);

    // This line will not work in this current state
    handle_decode(&mut bufreader)
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear, what you're asking. Neither `TcpStream` nor `BufReader` stores all the data in memory, in such a way that you can operate on it. You need to read it into some collection. Whether that's a `Vec` or a `BytesMut` shouldn't matter. (Note that I haven't used `BytesMut`, but the point remains)

Comment: I suppose what I'm really asking is: Is there a way to access the underlying buffer and use it as a BytesMut,  so that I can operate on the data whilst it is still reading?

The alternative is for me to prepend a length on encoded data so that I can read exactly enough bytes from the buffered reader, then pass that into the decode routine... But I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: The short answer is _"no"_. However, `TcpListener` does implement [`AsFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/fd/trait.AsFd.html), [`AsRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/fd/trait.AsRawFd.html), [`AsSocket`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/io/trait.AsSocket.html), and [`AsRawSocket`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/io/trait.AsRawSocket.html). So technically, you might be able to use these and OS specific APIs to access the underlying data. Whether you should do that, is a waaay separate question. The short answer is, it's probably better to write the data into a buffer

Comment: Thank you for your input. Since I have full control of the wire protocol anyways, I'll just prepend a length. Kind of sucks because I was hoping to avoid allocations as much as possible. I'll add it to the research pile and do the simpler way for now. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you're working on embedded, then it might be important. But otherwise allocating memory isn't always bad. I definitely do myself always limit allocation when possible. But even then if it's too much of a hassle, then sometimes you just have to go the "easy" route. I know about embedded devices running JavaScript, which is definitely _a lot worse_ than allocating a buffer. Also writing the length before any data with a non-fixed length, is what a lot of protocols and serialization strategies does as well on lower levels :)

Comment: [`byteorder`](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder) can "_pick off bytes in the right order_" from any `Write` implementor, including `TcpStream`. As for "_cloning cheaply_", any primitive type is cheap to clone, so I don't see the added value of `BytesMut` for that…

Comment: It's a highly concurrent server handling connection to potentially thousands of simultaneous low bandwidth devices with a strong emphasis on real-time. That's the main reason I'm looking to go down the zero allocations route... Thankfully I've never had to do embedded JS, that sounds like torture lol.

Comment: As for the cloning cheaply, I mean it's not cloning *at all*. It makes a shallow copy and uses reference counting.

Comment: If you want to access the underlying buffer of a `BufReader`, it is available as [`buffer()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.buffer) or [`fill_buf()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#method.fill_buf). Getting it as a `BytesMut` is something that cannot be done since it's not the same type, but you can use the `byteorder` crate, or build your own buffered reader with `BytesMut`.

Comment: Either way, I don't see how you can use this `BytesMut` as `Bytes`, since if you [freeze](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html#method.freeze) it you won't be able to read into it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[`BytesMut`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html) already buffer its content, there is no need for another buffer. You either use `BytesMut` or `BufReader` not both.

Using the trait `BufMut` you can use [`writer`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/buf/trait.BufMut.html#method.writer) this will return you a wrapper that implement Write from std. Then you need to implement yourself what does [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) of std, I didn't find anything that already do it for you. Or you could prefer use the [`BufMut`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/buf/trait.BufMut.html) trait instead of std trait directly.

```rust
use anyhow::Context;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use bytes::BytesMut;

fn bind_accept() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    fn handle_decode(buf: &mut bytes::BytesMut) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    let l = TcpListener::bind("1234")?;

    let (sock, _) = l.accept().context("should bind to provided port")?;

    let mut buf = BytesMut::with_capacity(1024);
    
    // read socket with BytesMut as buffer here

    handle_decode(&mut buf)
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning when you say that `BytesMut` buffers it's content? 

I can't find anywhere in the docs stating that it does such? 

The whole point of my question was to try and see whether there was an easy way to access the underlying buffer from a `BufReader` as a `BufMut` but it appears there is no sane way to do this.

Comment: @LewisFarnworth "BytesMut can be thought of as containing a buf: Arc<Vec<u8>>, an offset into buf, a slice length, and a guarantee that no other BytesMut for the same buf overlaps with its slice." "BytesMut’s BufMut implementation will implicitly grow its buffer as necessary. However, explicitly reserving the required space up-front before a series of inserts will be more efficient."